# Scala - choose a method of one trait over another

Tags: scala, traits

I am new to scala. I was learning traits and it seems that they can have concrete methods. Here is the code I have written.

```
trait A{
    def print : Unit = {
        println("I am in A")
    }
}

trait B{
    def print : Unit = {
        println("I am in B")
    }
}

trait C {
    def print : Unit = {
        println("I am in C")
    }
}

class D extends A with B with C{
}


object Main extends App {
    val d: D = new D
    d.print
}
```

It is giving a compilation error obviously. The compiler is asking me to override the print method in **D**. I don't want to write a new method. I just want to choose **C**'s print method over others. Is there any way I can choose only **C**'s print method? I hope I have made myself clear. I am sorry if the question sounds stupid. I am trying to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem of writing  this oneline `override def print = super.print`  in D. ?. It will call only C's Method.

Comment: @S.K, thank you. What if I want B's print or A's print?

Comment: change order of inheritance  as `class D extends A with C with B`

Comment: @S.K, so the last trait I mix in is the super class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @S.K, so the last trait I mix in is the super class?

If you look at the documention of Scala trait, whenever scala compiler see any class with multiple parent scala compiler will place all the classes in stackable form.

so If **A extends B with C** will become --> A->B->C and when you invoke super from you base class A it will consider method like C->B (C then B).

same way if you make **A extends C with B** will become --> A->C->B and when you invoke it compiler will consider B->C (B then C).

Please see more detials on scala trait stackable at below link.

[Scala's Stackable Trait Pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with S.K what is a problem to override in class D.

One way you are extending your D class with C and without overriding how can you get the handle of method in C?

You have to override in order to call it's method.